# If condition in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I check whether each of there are any rows in df4 which meets the condition.
But it throws the error "indices are out of bounds". Any help would be appreciated.

```
if (df4[df4['Occurences']] >= 5).any():
 df7 = df4[df4['Occurences'] >= 5].reset_index()
 df8 = df7[['MachineName','DateTime','Occurences']]
 rpt = dataframeToHtmlTable(df8)    
 sendNotificationAlive(rpt, ['sridevibaskaran@geotab.com'])
```

Comment: this looks wrong: `if (df4[df4['Occurences']] >= 5).any():` isn't it should be `if (df4[df4['Occurences'] >= 5]).any():`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first line:

```
if (df4[df4['Occurences']] >= 5).any():
```

looks wrong, the closing square brace should include the condition:

```
if (df4[df4['Occurences'] >= 5]).any():
```